# Unaccepting, then Accepting Old Answer Gives Rep (Again?)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation, accepted-answer

I was looking at an old question of mine, to which I've already accepted an answer. I discovered that unaccepting an answer, then accepting it again right away granted me 2 rep! This only works once per answer.

I don't know if a rep recalc will clear that rep gain or not.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this on MSO.

Comment: Can't duplicate it on MSO or SO.

Comment: Was the old accepted answer _your_ answer, and new accepted answer someone else's?

Comment: It was not my answer. I just tried it again with a different question and it failed. I also noticed that one of my rep gains from this bug disappeared, but one of them is still there. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308/is-there-a-version-control-system-for-database-structure-changes/360#360 for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer you can test with.

Comment: This will not work becuase its com answer